# Pressing the reset button on a motor shield of arduino blocks the program even when we re-upload?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

acctually i'm working on an arduino motor shield and i got to controle the two motors as the chassis moved forward and backward as i asked it to . But i came to press the 'Reset' button then everything just stopped moving . I tried to make the program work again by re-uploading but nothing happened . The program doesn't move the wheels anymore . What happened ? and what to do? Please help me .
PS: i'm using a 9v battery (and i'm only connecting it to uno board) , should i connect it to both the power pin in the shield and the arduino UNO board , to make it work properly? Hmm because sometimes the ultrason seems to have a problem of detecting the distances fast , probably a lack of energy problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to program the arduino uno without the shield and after burning the program, connect the shield. If it doesn't work, then there must be a power supply problem to the motors. The power coming to the motor is not enough perhaps to drive it.